# Dryer vent clogged flow sense

Tags: dryer, ducts

I had a dryer that I was using for awhile and it started taking forever for the clothes to finish drying, it felt super moist and warm inside the dryer. I preassumed the dryer was the issue, I replaced it with a brand new lg sensor dryer. Had it for a day and the dryer is doing the same exact issue. I already bought the duct brush that has a rod from Amazon to go in the wall to clean the lint out. My issue now is that, I have on the bottom floor of a two story apartment, when I sent the brush as far as a could it was a hitting something metal but it did not feel as I was reach anywhere near outside as I’m on the bottom floor. Trying to figure out how to fix this issue

Comment: A clogged vent can be a fire hazard. An apartment's maintenance people should be eager to fix it. Is this actually your responsibility?